# Programa para verificar número de palavras e uma sentença de um arquivo texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, revisão-de-código

arquivo texto utilizado: https://easyupload.io/j5agtq O método faz parte de uma classe chamada ArqTexto

Objetivo: O método não utiliza entrada e retorna, em um objeto tuple, (1) o número médio de palavras por sentença no arquivo, (2) o número de palavras na sentença com mais palavras e (3) o número de palavras na sentença com menos palavras. Você pode considerar que os símbolos que delimitam uma sentença sejam '!?.'.

O que eu fiz:

```
def media(self):
    import string
    marcadores = ["?", ".", "!"]
    cont = 0
    total_pal = 0
    num_frases = 0
    qtdade_palavras = []
    frase = ""
    with open(arq) as f:
        texto = f.read()
        # print(texto)
        for char in texto:
            frase += char

            if char in marcadores:
                # print(frase)
                # print(len(frase.split()))
                for pal in frase.split():
                    for i in string.punctuation:
                        if i in pal:
                            pal = pal.replace(i, "")
                    pal = pal.lower()
                    cont += 1

                # print(cont)
                total_pal += cont
                num_frases += 1
                frase = ""
                qtdade_palavras.append(cont)
                cont = 0
                continue
    print(f"O numero médio de palavras por sentença é {total_pal / num_frases}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com mais palavras é {max(qtdade_palavras)}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com menos palavras é {min(qtdade_palavras)}")
```

A saída da minha função:

```
O numero médio de palavras por sentença é 25.488888888888887
O número de palavras na sentença com mais palavras é 124
O número de palavras na sentença com menos palavras é 2
```

Observei que, na verdade, a sentença com menos palavras tem apenas 1 palavra e não DUAS:

```
`Prophet!
```

O que estou errando?

código fonte completo: https://www.pastiebin.com/5df6940dbc109

Comment: Não conseguir encontrar nenhum erro, tentei reproduzir o código e tudo saiu bem com os resultados esperados, o problema pode esta no aquivo de texto que você esteja abrindo, se puder coloque todo o arquivo que é aberto em `with open(arq) as f:`, fora isso, só algumas linhas que poderiam ser removidas que não fazem diferença a não ser que faça algo em outra parte do código

Comment: @Guilherme França de Oliveira: Vou editar e colocar o link do código completo

Comment: @Guilherme França de Oliveira   código completo:  https://www.pastiebin.com/5df6940dbc109

Comment: Conseguiria disponibilizar o arquivo `raven.txt`? que talvez a solução do problema esteja nele, que o código em si esta rodando bem, reproduzindo ele aqui utilizando um arquivo qualquer esta obtendo a saída correta, tem algumas coisas que você tem que arrumar no seu código, porém, postarei aqui quando tiver a solução completa

Comment: @Guilherme França de Oliveira  Está na pergunta:   https://easyupload.io/j5agtq

Answer (score 1):

Em seu código esta coletando a frase até uma pontuação especifica e verificando quantas palavras há nela, no caso o seu arquivo onde se encontra a palavra `Prophet!` esta assim um pouco antes

```
Quoth the raven, `Nevermore.'

`Prophet!' said I, `thing of evil! - prophet still, if bird or devil! -
```

ele termina a frase anterior no `.` e começa uma nova no `'`, deixando a frase assim `' 'Prophet!` sendo que ele conta como palavra os parenteses, o que você pode fazer é acrescentar no código essa linha

```
frase = frase.replace('`', '').replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
```

deixando assim

```
def media(self):
    import string
    marcadores = ["?", ".", "!"]
    cont = 0
    total_pal = 0
    num_frases = 0
    qtdade_palavras = []
    frase = ""
    with open(self.arq) as f:
        texto = f.read()
        # print(texto)
        for char in texto:
            frase += char

            if char in marcadores:
                print(frase)
                # print(len(frase.split()))
                frase = frase.replace('`', '').replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
                for pal in frase.split():
                    for i in string.punctuation:
                        if i in pal:
                            pal = pal.replace(i, "")
                    pal = pal.lower()
                    cont += 1

                # print(cont)
                total_pal += cont
                num_frases += 1
                frase = ""
                qtdade_palavras.append(cont)
                cont = 0
                continue
    print(f"O numero médio de palavras por sentença é {total_pal / num_frases}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com mais palavras é {max(qtdade_palavras)}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com menos palavras é {min(qtdade_palavras)}")
```

Outra coisa que você deveria muda no seu código é quando você abre os arquivos, na sua `__ini__` você da um parâmetro a sua classe que seria o nome do arquivo e instancia já fornecendo o arquivo, porem quando você chama o método ele não usa o arquivo da `__init__` e sim da sua variável global, para corrigi isso utilize 'self'

```
with open(self.arq) as f:
```

que caso você mude a variável global, não altera o valor do objeto instanciado

fora algumas linhas que diria ser inúteis no meio do seu código que não acrescenta em nada a não ser que tenha planos para elas

por exemplo o `continue` no final do `for` sendo que assim que ele termina ja deverá recomeçar automaticamente, no caso você deveria usar caso no meio do `for` os caminhos vão para lugares diferentes

fiz umas modificações em seu código para deixa o mais organizado, mas não removi as linha que acho inúteis, segue o link https://repl.it/repls/OverdueNavyblueNetbsd

---

### Edit

outra maneira de resolver seria utilizando o `if`

```
def media(self):
    import string
    marcadores = ["?", ".", "!"]
    cont = 0
    total_pal = 0
    num_frases = 0
    qtdade_palavras = []
    frase = ""
    with open(self.arq) as f:
        texto = f.read()
        # print(texto)
        for char in texto:
            if char not in "`'" + '"-':
                frase += char

                if char in marcadores:
                    print(frase)
                    # print(len(frase.split()))
                    for pal in frase.split():
                        for i in string.punctuation:
                            if i in pal:
                                pal = pal.replace(i, "")
                        pal = pal.lower()
                        cont += 1

                    # print(cont)
                    total_pal += cont
                    num_frases += 1
                    frase = ""
                    qtdade_palavras.append(cont)
                    cont = 0
                    continue
    print(f"O numero médio de palavras por sentença é {total_pal / num_frases}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com mais palavras é {max(qtdade_palavras)}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com menos palavras é {min(qtdade_palavras)}")
```

---

### edit 2

Estava um pouco sem o que fazer por agora e resolvi te mostrar uma resolução um pouco mais curta para que de uma olhada e tente tirar proveito, espero que ajude

```
def media(self):
    with open(self.arq) as f:
        import re
        texto = f.read()
        frases = re.split(r'[!?.]\W+\b', texto.replace('\n', ' '))
        palavras = [len(frase.replace('-', '').split()) for frase in frases]

    print(f"O numero médio de palavras por sentença é {sum(palavras) / len(frases)}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com mais palavras é {max(palavras)}")
    print(f"O número de palavras na sentença com menos palavras é {min(palavras)}")
```

Comment: consegue imaginar uma maneira mais simples de resolver do que a que eu tentei?

Comment: Outra coisa que esqueci de falar é que ele também ta contando o `-` como palavram, sendo necessário  remover ele também, pensei uma maneira diferente de resolver também, postarei acima

Comment: acrescentei uma versão reduzida no final, de uma olhada e vê o que acha e boa sorte!